# Definitions--Strictly Speaking

Tags: general-topology, definition

I am working on [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805274/is-retract-of-a-hausdorff-space-closed-in-that-space):

> If $Z$ is a topological space, we call $Y \subset Z$ a retract of $Z$ if there is a continuous map $r:Z \rightarrow Y$ such that $r(y)=y$ for all $y \in Y$. Show that if $Z$ is Hausdorff and $Y$ a retract of $Z$, then $Y$ is closed in $Z$?

Referring to the link, it seems that most the solutions rely on the fact that if a point $z \in Z$ satisfies $r(z)=z$, then $z \in Y$. But, if I am not mistaken, this isn't, strictly speaking, stipulated in the problem statement. In the problem statement, it says that $r(y)=y$ for each $y \in Y$, which I take to mean the following: if $y \in Y$, then $r(y)=y$. This, obviously, does not imply (is not equivalent to, does not mean, etc.) that if a point $z \in Z$ satisfies $r(z)=z$, then $z \in Y$. Am I right in thinking that the solution relies on this other conditional, and therefore the problem is stated poorly? I noticed this happens a lot in mathematical texts. E.g., definitions will often be of the form "... if ..." or "If..., then..." But really there should be "if and only if', since the purpose of a definition is to establish an equivalence.

Comment: But $r:Z\to Y$, so if $z\notin Y$ and $r(z)=z$, then $r$ maps outside of $Y$, impossible.

Comment: Definitions are always "if and only if" statements, but it is traditional not to write this.  I agree, it's a very bad tradition.

Comment: I think it's a *fine* tradition.  A definition is not a proposition.  It is declaring what something means, i.e. what something *is*.  And it goes without saying that something *is* itself if and only if it is itself.  No need to declare that *if* you are defining something.  But once you start making *inferences* then it does matter.  I think it only when you have two equivalent statements that need to be proven to be true if and only if the other is true, so *either* could be used as a definition, that this seems hinky.  But it isn't.

Comment: @Clayton D'oh! Thanks!

Comment: I mean, if the definition is: "a thing is a BLOOP if it does the kinkaboop".  So "does the kinkaboop $\implies$ BLOOP".  But, says the bright student, it was never stated that "BLOOP $\implies$ does the kinkaboop".  Well, ... okay, but what does "BLOOP" *mean* in this case?  As BLOOP was only defined in terms of doing the kinkaboop, it simply isn't possible for $BLOOP$ and $\lnot$ does the kinkaboop.  So BLOOP *does* $\implies$ does the kinkaboop after all.  And, by definition, BLOOP $\iff$ does the kinkaboop.

Comment: But it is a good and valid observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition, $r$ is function $Z \to Y$, so for any point $z \in Z$, $r(z) \in Y$ -- otherwise, it wouldn't be a function $Z \to Y$.