# Hausdorff topological space and graph of a continuous function.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space and $A$ a subspace of $X$. Show that if exists a continuous application $f:X\to A$ such that $f_{|A}=id_A$, then $A$ is a closed set in $X$.

My third attempt is this:

Because $X$ is Hausdorff, the subspace  $\Delta_X=\{(x,x)\in X\times X, \quad x\in X\}$ is closed in the product topology on $X\times X$.

Let $\Gamma_f=\{(x,f(x), \quad x\in X\}\subseteq X\times A$ the graph of $f$.

By hypothesis, $f_{|A}=id_A$, so $\Gamma_X\cap \Delta_X=\Delta_A=\{(x,x), \quad x\in A\}$.

Now, by definition of subspace topology, $\Delta_A$ is closed in $\Gamma_f$ because $\Delta_X$ is closed. Moreover, $f$ is continuous, so exists $\phi:X\to \Gamma_f$ homeomorphism defined by $\phi(x)=(x,f(x))$. In particular, $\phi$ is continuous and so $\phi^{-1}(\Delta_A)=A$ is closed in $X$.

Does it work?

Comment: That looks good to me, provided you are allowed to take the fact that $\Gamma_f$ is closed as background knowledge.

Comment: By the way, if you are familiar with nets, you can try to write a different, much shorter proof.

Comment: @RobArthan Actually, I think this step is unnecessary. At the end OP used closedness only in $\Gamma_f$, not in $X\times X$. And $\Delta_A=\Delta_X\cap\Gamma_f$ is closed in $\Gamma_f$ by definition of the induced topology. (since $\Delta_X$ is closed in $X\times X$)

Comment: @RobArthan I think they don't even need that fact. They require only that $\Delta_A$ is closed *in $\Gamma_f$* - which follows from closedness of $\Delta_X$ - and that $\phi:X\cong\Gamma_f$ really is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @FShrike Seems like only the continuity of $\phi$ was used here, not the continuity of the inverse.

Comment: @Mark $\phi$ is a homeomorphism iff. it is continuous (it's always open actually, the inverse is always continuous) iff. $f$ is continuous, and $\Delta_X$ is closed iff. $X$ is Hausdorff, and so the method of proof works if $f$ is continuous and $X$ is Hausdorff : ) But I agree we don't need the observation $\phi^{-1}$ is continuous (but it is always true)

Comment: @Mark: you are very likely right. I was commenting on the proof as presented.

Comment: @FShrike Right, because $\phi(U)=(U\times X)\cap\Gamma_f$. I probably forgot that, or just never noticed that before. Most of the time continuity is much easier to prove than homeomorphism, that's why I was surprised when you mentioned that stronger condition. I thought I might be missing something.

Comment: Thank you all! Yes, actually I introduced that homeomorphism but I only used its continuity :) Could someone help me visualize why $\Gamma_f\cap \Delta_X=\Delta_A$?

Answer (score 1):

Note this is the property RC, that is, Retracts are Closed. The proof that T2 is sufficient for RC is [T310 of pi-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000310) and was discussed at [is retract of a hausdorff space closed in that space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805274)

I'd change your proof to just note that since $\Delta_A$ is closed and $x\mapsto_g(x,x)$ is continuous, $g^{\leftarrow}[\Delta_A]=A$ is closed. I also agree that the fact that the continuous graph of a function is closed may need more support.

Comment: Ok thanks, I can also not use the fact that the graph is closed, as was suggested. I just made the changes, do you agree?

Comment: Do you suggest to avoid using homeomorphism because I can just use the fact that $f$ acts as the identity on $A$?